# Upgrade WordPress to latest version in Linux

Tags: linux, wordpress, command, upgrade

Is there any way one could easily upgrade WordPress to latest version in Linux apart from the [traditional way](https://wordpress.org/support/article/upgrading-wordpress-extended-instructions/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one way that I usually prefer when upgrading WordPress but this requires you to be comfortable with Linux shell prompt.

It is basically four step process:

Step 1 : Backup your existing database and WordPress directory

> ```
> $ mkdir -p /backup/21072016
> $ mysqldump -u user -p wp_database > /backup/21072016/wp_database.sql
> $ tar -zcvf /backup/21072016/app.tar.gz /var/www/sites/mysite.com/app
> ```

Step 2 : Download the latest version from [here](http://wordpress.org/latest.zip)

> ```
> $ cd /tmp
> $ wget http://wordpress.org/latest.zip
> $ unzip latest.zip
> ```

Step 3 : Execute below commands

> ```
> $ cd /var/www/sites/mysite.com/app
> $ cp -avr /tmp/wordpress/* .
> $ rm -rf /tmp/wordpress /tmp/latest.zip
> ```

Step 4 : Open a browser and run upgrade script as `http://app.mysite.com/wp-admin/upgrade.php`

Step 5 : This is optional, but due to security reasons I prefer renaming the upgrade.php file stored in wp-admin directory

That's it.. You are done..

Comment: Step 4 includes a human interaction with a web browser page, and is apparently just to update the DB if required.

Can we get rid of that and check for/auto-update the DB from the CLI as well?